# Sort by enum values in mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sorting, mongoose

I am trying to render only one of enum values by using this in controller:

```
exports.list = (req, res) => {
    let sortBy = req.query.sortBy ? req.query.sortBy : "_id";
    
    Event.find()
        .sort([[sortBy]])
        .exec((err, events) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Events not found'
                });
            }
            res.json(events);
        });
};
```

This is my model schema:

```
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeEvent: {
            type: String,
            default: "Flight",
            enum: ["Flight", "Drive"] 
        },
    },
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

And them I want render only events of "Drive" values in React:

```
const getEvents = (sortBy) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/events?sortBy=${sortBy}`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

const [showEvents, setShowEvents] = useState([]);

  const loadEvents = () => {
    getEvents("typeEvent").then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setShowEvents(data);
      }
    });
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadEvents();
  }, []);
```

I can only add that this syntax renders both of values, what did I wrong ?

Comment: So you are trying to "filter" the documents which have "Drive" value by sorting?

Comment: Instead of `.sort([[sortBy]])` use `.where({ typeEvent: sortBy })` Also your sort is not even close to what it should be, see docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: `.where({ typeEvent: sortBy })` solved my issue, thanks a lot